# Cannot install code blocks from Ubuntu Software Centre

Tags: software-installation

it displays a window  that says Requires installation of untrusted packages it says:

```
This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.

details--codeblocks codeblocks-common codeblocks-contrib gamin libcodeblocks0 libgamin0 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxsmithlib0 valgrind
```

the pop up window also has two options: **ok** and **repair**.

when i am trying to click Ok it doesn't do anything and when i am trying to click repair the window appears another 3-4 times and in progress one program called update cache is running but the cache didnt get updated and apart from that i updated cache from the update centre.

Please Help

Comment: Could you run `apt-get install codeblocks` in terminal and post the output? Those messages often provide more details than the GUI ones. Remember that you can _[edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/605913/edit)_ your question, don't post it as comment or answer. And please use code formatting (select passage and click on the `<$>` button). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### First possbile solution

Open dash -> Software Sources

Make sure every checkbox from this tab is checked (all of them, also the sources one), also the "Download from" is set to Main server.

[image]

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

### Second, if the first does not work - You can try adding and installing it from the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pasgui/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

### If it did not work, you can follow official page guide for installing under ubuntu:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks_nightly_build_on_Ubuntu

1. Install the compiler. `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
2. Install the debugger. `sudo apt-get install gdb`

You'll need to install wxWidgets to use Codeblocks. Revisions from 4051 and after use wxWidgets 2.8.4. If you want to install them, make sure you have your universe and multiverse repositories enabled and install the following packages.

3. Install wxWidgets library. (This package is all that is needed to run any application that uses wxWidgets. ie. Code::Blocks)
   `sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-0`
4. Install the wxWidgets developement packages. (This is used to develop wxWidgets applications of your own.)
   `sudo apt-get install libwxgtk2.8-dev`
5. (OPTIONAL) Install the wxWidgets documentation.
   `sudo apt-get install wx2.8-doc`

### Now go get the nightly build and install it. All dependencies should now be met.

1. Get the latest nigtly build of Code::Blocks from the nightly builds forum.
2. Install Code::Blocks.

   `sudo dpkg -i <Name_Of_Daily_Build.deb>`

NOTE: Since revision 4281 and after, the nightly builds are made differently. Codeblocks is now packaged into separate Debian packages and the packages are archived together in a tar.gz file.

1. Download the tar.gz file to your computer and extract the files to an empty directory, such as one called temp for example.
   `tar xvf CB_date-of-build_revision-number_Ubuntu6.10+7.04_wx2.8.4.tar.gz`
2. Install all the packages at the same time.
   `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

The packages can be installed individually, if you prefer not to install everything. The first package to install is libcodeblocks0 followed by the codeblocks package. All the other packages are optional. If you want to install the wxsmith and/or contrib packages, you must install the libwxsmithlib0 package first.

Comment: i got my problem solved.used sudo apt-get clean and then tried to install the code blocks.installation was successful